# Empty GridView with borders

Tags: java, android, gridview, border, grid-layout

http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple1/v4/8f/96/0e/8f960eda-413d-c1c2-fcf0-178e9206fbe2/source/392x696bb.jpg

I want to make an empty gridview like the image above. I created grid view in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="90"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then I created grid view object in my activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_painting);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview); 

}
```

But I can't see the borders. Also I can't see any cell and can't click as expected.

How can I create a grid view with empty cells, also with borders.

Thanks in advance.